# WSSE - Sign an element inside soapenv:Header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, wss4j

I want to add **wsse:security** to my soap message. This is my code:

```
    public Document signSoapMessage(SOAPMessage message) {
    try {
        Document doc = message.getSOAPBody().getOwnerDocument();
        Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties); //File

        WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader(doc);
        secHeader.insertSecurityHeader();

        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file"));

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(inStream, properties.getProperty("privatekeypassword").toCharArray());

        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

        WSSecSignature sign = new WSSecSignature(secHeader);
        sign.setX509Certificate(cert);
        sign.setUserInfo(properties.getProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias"), properties.getProperty("privatekeypassword"));
        sign.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE); // Binary Security Token - SecurityTokenReference
        sign.setUseSingleCertificate(true);
        sign.setDigestAlgo(DigestMethod.SHA1);

        //sign.build(crypto);
        Document signedDoc = sign.build(crypto);

        return signedDoc;
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (WSSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works for **soapenv:Body** (It does add **wsu:Id** and **xmlns:wsu** parameters)

But there is an extra element in **soapenv:Header** and it doesn't sign this element. There is no  **wsu:Id** and **xmlns:wsu** parameters and lack of one ds:Reference.

Example of not signed soap msg:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <!-- this element should be signed but is not - NOT WORKING -->
    <something>
    </something>

   </soapenv:Header>
   <!-- this element should be signed and It does. -->
   <soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

*I compare soap msg from my program to working soap msg from SoapUI project.*

When I post a message to web service I get an error: `wsse:InvalidSecurity - Soap Header must be signed`. While in SoupUI it does works.

So my question is how can I force **WSS4j** to sign extra element inside **soapenv:Header** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the problem.

Normally this code should work in my situation.

```
//strange static method from apache o.O
org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
List<WSEncryptionPart> wsEncryptionParts = new ArrayList<>();
WSEncryptionPart somethingPart = new WSEncryptionPart("something","somethingNamespace","");
wsEncryptionParts.add(somethingPart);
sign.addReferencesToSign(wsEncryptionParts);
```

Nevertheless, It doesn't work. It always throws an exception:

> org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No message with ID
>   "noXMLSig" found in resource bundle
>   "org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity". Original Exception was
>   a org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException and message No
>   message with ID "noEncElement" found in resource bundle
>   "org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity"

I could not find an answer to what is wrong with my soap message or code.

However, after a time of debugging of **org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature**. I felt that something is wrong with the class. I decided to modify a method **build(Crypto cr)**.

```
public Document build(Crypto cr) throws WSSecurityException {
        LOG.debug("Beginning signing...");
        this.prepare(cr);
        if (this.getParts().isEmpty()) {
            this.getParts().add(WSSecurityUtil.getDefaultEncryptionPart(this.getDocument()));

            // --- Here is my edit - And it works!

            WSEncryptionPart aaa = new WSEncryptionPart("something","somethingNamespace","");
            this.getParts().add(aaa);

            // ----------------------------------

        } else {
            Iterator var2 = this.getParts().iterator();

            label33:
            while(true) {
                while(true) {
                    if (!var2.hasNext()) {
                        break label33;
                    }

                    WSEncryptionPart part = (WSEncryptionPart)var2.next();
                    if (part.getId() == null && "STRTransform".equals(part.getName())) {
                        part.setId(this.strUri);
                    } else if ("KeyInfo".equals(part.getName()) && "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#".equals(part.getNamespace()) && part.getElement() == null) {
                        Element keyInfoElement = this.getKeyInfoElement();
                        part.setElement(keyInfoElement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference> referenceList = this.addReferencesToSign(this.getParts());
        this.computeSignature(referenceList);
        if (this.bstToken != null) {
            this.prependBSTElementToHeader();
        }

        return this.getDocument();
    }
```

Of course, the solution is quite weak. Yet, at least it works now.

The problem exists in the newest version:

**wss4j-ws-security-dom 2.2.2**

**wss4j-ws-security-common 2.2.2**

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is supposed to work that way:

```
        WSSecSignature sign = new WSSecSignature(secHeader);
        sign.getParts().addAll(getEncryptionParts());
```

With getEncryptionParts() being the WSEncryptionPart List you want to add.
If added that way, the build method is capable of finding them, without patching the framework.